# Getting started with Fuse

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am really excited about the Fuse IDE and the Data Mapper.

However, I have had issues getting started, probably due to my lack of understanding.
I have tried numerous combinations of Eclipse/JBoss (Kepler, Luna, Mars) and examples and all fail when I try to create a Data Map.
The problem I get is "System ID  isn´t absolute."

Can you please assist me in how to get started?

I have downloaded the examples from: fuseide/examples/transformation at master · fusesource/fuseide · GitHub

Patrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you followed the install guide at: http://tools.jboss.org/blog/integration-stack-4.2.2.Final-for-luna.html ?
That should let u setup the JBDS with the Integration Stack which Fuse IDE and DataMapper are part of. (be aware that the Transformation Tooling is still tech preview / early access so you need to enable Early Access on the JBoss Central page.

Examples for the tranformation tooling can be found here:
https://github.com/fusesource/fuseide/tree/master/examples/transformation

For further help/questions you can always shoot an email to our public mailing list at: jbosstools-fuse-dev@lists.jboss.org.
Be sure to subscribe to that list first: https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/jbosstools-fuse-dev

You can also visit our IRC channel on Freenode called #fusetools and say hello or ask questions :D

Thanks
Lars